# why keyboard input lags while using Zoom app

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, lag, io

Every time I am **using Zoom App** or Google Meet, The **keyboard input is delayed terribly (about 3s+) while typing in any kind of application.**

I tried to reinstall Zoom again, deactivate my antiVirus (ESET ) but nothing that I tried seems to help. it also happens regardless if the camera and mic are on or off.

It's also worth noting that while using Zoom the fans make more noise.

The problem occurs only while using Zoom and Google meet (maybe more like them idk ) with Skype everything works just fine.

My internet connection is fine (I tried in many places with different computers and it worked there). when looking in Task Manager, CPU and RAM are not heavily utilized (30-50 %).
I also checked for any malware, I run a scan with Malwarebytes, whatever it found it deleted it, but the problem still happens.

**System and Hardware:**

- Windows 10 latest, on a Lenovo ThinkPad L390,8th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-8565U...4 cores
- 32 GB RAM, SSD drive with 320 GB free.
- pc is about 1.5-year-old in good condition.

My suspicion is that inner software is conflicting with Zoom and prevent it from getting some of the resources, but I don't know what can it be, or if it is even the reason.

I'll be glad to hear any ideas on why it may happen and how to fix it.

Comment: Try: (1) Disable your security software if it's not Windows Defender. (2) Check if this happens when you [boot in Safe Mode with Networking](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234) to see if some installed is causing the problem (if Zoom works in this mode).

Comment: Get or make a bootable USB key that has a simple browser and see if Zoom works in that.  Boot to Safe Mode and check Zoom and keyboard in that.

Comment: Try opening voice recorder, start recording, and try typing, if the lag occurs, it might be the audio driver is the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help!

I couldn't boot in safe mode because it shut down my internet connection and I couldn't get easily the right ethernet cable.

eventually, I performed clean boot instead, and I found that the program that has conflicted with Zoom calls Fortemedia APO Control service, so I disabled the service.